# Opening .pkl file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am trying to open .pkl file, but keep getting the following error:

```
import pickle

with open('/exp/model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)

--> _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'Z'.


import pickle

with open('/exp/model.pkl', 'r') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)

--> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 23: invalid continuation byte
```

(difference is in the file opening mode). I tried probably all the possible combinations, and didn't find similar errors on SO. Would appreciate help and advises.

I am using Python3, Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: How did you create the file?

Comment: What do you get if you run this command in shell? `file /exp/model.pkl`

Comment: @falsetru I get: model.pkl: data

Comment: @jordanm This file was created by RLLab. Example of how it is read is here: https://github.com/openai/rllab/blob/872511883f1c415bb933e612a2a5b622c56be9b2/scripts/resume_training.py#L55